# Getting an 2002 error message while upgrading ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, mysql

I am doing upgrade of ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. I am getting 2002 error message. I am also attaching a screenshot for that
How could I solve this error message?
I also check mysqld.sock. It seems to be empty. 
[Error 2002(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3o6h.png)

[error 2002(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjXSp.png)

Thanks

Comment: Based on the screen shots, do you have a backup of your database? If not do you have command line access to `mysql`? If so make a backup with `mysql dump` before doing anything else.   http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mysqldump.1.html

Comment: One post identifies the lack of `mysql-server` as the problem. Do you have it installed?  
 
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server` to install mysql on ubuntu – towry Feb 4 '14 at 12:36  from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run  ----- Please read ALL the posts in the cited thread for extra insight.

Comment: I already take a backup of that... Yes, my mysql is installed as mysql-server..